# simple trigger update on different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Let's say I have the following tables (primary keys in bold, -> symbol indicates a functional dependency)

**state_name**, surface, habitants (Table States)

**HsCode**->HsName,state_name (Table High_Schools)

**Security_Social_Number**->name, address (TABLE student)

TABLE Student_Apply (**Social_Number,HsCode**,University_degree)

Let's say we already filled the data and now we want to modify (delete or update) some rows in States table.

If we delete a state from Table States, all rows in other tables containing this State should be deleted. If instead we change the state_name, other changes should change this value.

How should we achieve that? implementing triggers? constraints? I will use postgreSQL but I suppose it's a very generic question.

In that case we change a primary key; the solution would be different if it would be a non primary key field?

thanks in advance

Comment: One use of triggers is to maintain referential integrity amongst tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a foreign key with  `ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`. It will delete the row in the referencing table if the parent row is deleted and update the row in the referencing table if the parent row is updated.